# Question on whether the Lebesgue measure of this set is strictly positive

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\;f:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^{n-1} \to \mathbb R^m\;$ be a continuous function and consider some bounded, non-closed and with compact closure set  $\;\mathcal A\subset L^2(\mathbb R;\mathbb R^m)\;$ which consists of continuous functions $\;g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^m\;$.

We denote $\;d(f(\cdot,y),\mathcal A)=inf_{\;g\in \mathcal A\;} {\vert \vert
 f(x,y)-g(x) \vert \vert}_{L^2}\;$ and $\;B^{n-1}_R(y_0)\;$ stands for a ball in
 $\;\mathbb R^{n-1}\;$ of centre $\;y_0\;$ and radius $\;R\;$

**Question:**

> if $\;d(f(\cdot,y_0),\mathcal A)\gt 0\;$ for some $\;y_0 \in \mathbb R^{n-1}\;$ then is it true to claim that $\;\mathcal L^{n-1}(B^{n-1}_R(y_0) \cap \{y: d(f(\cdot,y),\mathcal A) \ge C \gt 0\})\gt 0\;$?

**My Attempt:**

Since $\;\exists y_0 \in \mathbb R^{n-1}\;$ such that $\;d(f(\cdot,y_0),\mathcal A) \gt 0\;$ the set $\;B^{n-1}_R(y_0) \cap \{y: d(f(\cdot,y),\mathcal A) \ge C \gt 0\}\;$ must be non-empty.

In addition, due to continuity of $\;f\;$, there should be a neighborhood of $\;y_0\;$(let me denote it as $\;\mathcal N(y_0)\;$) in which $\;d(f(\cdot,y),\mathcal A) \ge C \gt 0\;,\forall y \in \mathcal N(y_0)\;$

Hence, if I could claim that $\;\mathcal N(y_0):=B^{n-1}_R(y_0) \cap \{y: d(f(\cdot,y),\mathcal A) \ge C \gt 0\}\;$, the question would be answered immediately taking [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_positive_measure) into account.

However as I know, a neighborhood is an open set so I'm a bit unsure if I can claim the above since I can't see whether $\;B^{n-1}_R(y_0) \cap \{y: d(f(\cdot,y),\mathcal A) \ge C \gt 0\}\;$ is a Borel one.

It's been a really long time since I had my Measure Theory course so I apologize in advance if my question is quite elementary. I would appreciate if somebody could help me understand what I'm missing here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The set $\mathcal A$ is considered as a subset of what topological space? In order to talk about a distance from $f$ to $\mathcal A$ they have to be contained it the same metric space.

Comment: @AlexRavsky  I just edited it

Comment: The word "the" in the definition of $\mathcal{A}$ is confusing.  I guess you are not saying that $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of *all* continuous functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^m)$ (since that does not have compact closure), but it's just *some* set of continuous functions?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your remarks. I edited it once again. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: One other note is that the question doesn't change if you replace $\mathcal{A}$ by its closure, so you might as well just say $\mathcal{A}$ is compact.

Comment: @NateEldredge excuse me but, which question doesn't change? the first one, the second or both?

Comment: Both, because $d(g, \mathcal{A}) = d(g, \overline{\mathcal{A}})$ in any metric space.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, you're right! So this implies also that I could change the "inf" in the definition of distance into "min"?

Comment: Right.  By the way, "strictly positive" doesn't mean what you think - there are lots of Borel sets with Lebesgue measure zero.  The claim is that every nonempty *open* set has strictly positive Lebesgue measure.  But there's no good reason why your set should be open, nor is it clear that it must contain an open set.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks a lot for the explanation (it's true, I haven't understood it well). I also have to admitt I was a bit careless when posting this question. I edited my set , however i don't know if this would be still sufficient for my case